# Font Awesome 5 and Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I was using font-awesome npm package (which is Font Awesome 4.7 version) but I want to upgrade to Font Awesome 5. I've install the following packages :

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.13",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.13",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0",
```

I was using icons like this :

```
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

With the new version I tried to use icons like this :

```
<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-2x"></i>
```

But this is not working. I try to add icons like this :

```
import {faSignOutAlt} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
fontawesome.library.add(faSignOutAlt);
```

in my app.module.ts and it is working, but I don't want to import each icon one by one. Is there a way to use them like I was doing with the previous version ? Eather a way to not import them one by one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and use in .angular-cli

```
 "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
```

reference : 
[Using a Package Manager](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)

Comment: After trying to use 'angular-fontawesome' this way worked out easier for me upgrading from fa. 4 to 5 as icons in the project we're a mix of raw-codes in the css and pseudo elements, this way existing icons still work being backward compatible apart from a few alias icons. It seems 'angular-fontawesome' has become very cumbersome especially if your icon usage is low.

Comment: Why is this a dev dependency?

Comment: You're right, it should not be a development dependency.

Comment: and now you've just included *every* icon into your project by using this method

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you could import and add them all

```js
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

export class AppModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIconPacks(fas, far);
  }
}
```

[However](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/icon-library.md)

> You can also import entire icon styles. But be careful! This way of importing icons does not support tree-shaking, so all icons from the imported package will end up in the bundle.

Also, since you are using `angular-fontawesome`, use it:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FontAwesomeModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    // Add an icon to the library for convenient access in other components
    library.addIcons(faCoffee);
  }
}
```

and in html

```html
<!-- simple name only that assumes the default prefix -->
<fa-icon icon="coffee"></fa-icon>
<!-- ['fas', 'coffee'] is an array that indicates the [prefix, iconName] -->
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'coffee']"></fa-icon>
```

[All code taken from the official documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/icon-library.md)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this in angular 8 version. It's working perfectly.
Please follow this simple procedure:

1. First install it by angular cli

   npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
2. Open angular.json and update the css file as follow

   "styles": [
       "styles.css",
       "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"]
3. Restart your server

eg, how to add

```
<i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
```

Happy coding :)

[For more font awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free)

Comment: does this support treeshaking?

Comment: Please check more about [tree shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set css url in your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
```

Here is working example:

[Stackblitz example=> font-awesome](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzmvzb)